# Office 365 API get user details

Tags: office365

When I use the url

```
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users
```

I can get all users in a company, but how can I get more details about a specific user?

Such as in `Contacts`:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Contacts
```

There is very little information given in `Users` (`Email`, `Alias`, `DisplayName`). What if I need to get a user's phone or company name and so on? Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 3):

These are actually two different things. The Users node isn't "GET"-able, you have to supply a user ID in the form of an SMTP address, like:

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Users("sadie@contoso.com")
```

The Contacts API is used to access personal contacts only (the contacts a user has stored in their Contacts folder in their mailbox).

It sounds like you want to see users in the organization, in which case you want to use the [Azure AD Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151678.aspx). The user information for Office 365 is stored in Azure AD.

Comment: Can the Azure AD Graph API be retrieved with the same access token?

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn792115%28v=office.15%29.aspx#sectionSection2

> You can also retrieve information about a specific contact by using
> the Id property of the Contact entity.
>
> GET https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts(contactId)

Sample JSON Response: basically what you are looking for!

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('sadie@contoso.com')/Contacts('AAMkADA5...')",
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"EQAAABYAAACjVbBbHnDNQZzaeCbB94zAAABkh+ph\"",
  "@odata.editLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('sadie@contoso.com')/Contacts('AAMkADA5...')",
  "Id": "AAMkADA5...",
  "ChangeKey": "EQAAABYAAACjVbBbHnDNQZzaeCbB94zAAABkh+ph",
  "ClassName": "IPM.Contact",
  "Subject": "Alex Darrow",
  "BodyPreview": "",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "Text",
    "Content": ""
  },
  "Importance": "Normal",
  "Categories": [],
  "HasAttachments": false,
  "ParentFolderId": "AAMkADA5...",
  "Birthday": null,
  "FileAs": "Darrow, Alex",
  "DisplayName": "Alex Darrow",
  "GivenName": "Alex",
  "Initials": null,
  "MiddleName": null,
  "NickName": null,
  "Surname": "Darrow",
  "Title": null,
  "Generation": null,
  "EmailAddress1": "alex@alpineskihouse.com",
  "ImAddress1": null,
  "ImAddress2": null,
  "ImAddress3": null,
  "JobTitle": null,
  "CompanyName": null,
  "Department": null,
  "OfficeLocation": null,
  "Profession": null,
  "BusinessHomePage": null,
  "AssistantName": null,
  "Manager": null,
  "HomePhone1": null,
  "HomePhone2": null,
  "BusinessPhone1": null,
  "BusinessPhone2": null,
  "MobilePhone1": null,
  "OtherPhone": null,
  "DateTimeCreated": "2014-07-01T16:24:09Z",
  "LastModifiedTime": "2014-07-01T16:24:09Z",
  "Attachments@odata.navigationLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('sadie@contoso.com')/Contacts('AAMkADA5...')/Attachments"
}
```