# can't get login user profile detail in office 365

Tags: c#, php, api, office365

I'm trying to get login user detail(first name ,last name, etc) using [office 365 api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations#get-contacts), with method

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/Contacts
```

but its give me error

> {"error":{"code":"OAuthMissingForThisApiVersion","message":"Authentication for this API version requires OAuth."}}

and i also try with this( using this [**Reference of stackoverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530036/office-365-api-get-user-details))

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Users("myemail@onmicrosoft.com")
```

and it's give me error :

> {"error":{"code":"RequestBroker-ParseUri","message":"Syntax error:
>   character '\"' is not valid at position 0 in
>   '\"myemail@onmicrosoft.com\"'."}}

**Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.**

Comment: Try single quotes, or no quotes

Comment: @RST : i did it, but its not work. it say **Resource not found for the segment 'Users'**